# Find the number of integers $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ such that $1\leq x_1 \leq \dots x_k \leq n$

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to find the cardinality of the set

$$ S=\{(x_1,...,x_k)\in \Bbb{Z}^k \;|\; x_i \in \{1,\dots,n\},\; x_1\leq x_2 \leq...\leq x_k\}$$

If we had the condition $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_k$, the answer would be $0$ for $k > n$ and $n \choose k$ for $k \leq n$. However, allowing the entries to be nondistinct seems to make matters more complex.

Comment: Consider the combination with repetitions.

Comment: What does this symbol mean? The $k$ exactly. $\Bbb{Z}^k$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** replace $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ with $(x_1, x_2+1,\ldots, x_k+k-1)$.

Comment: Very elegant approach.

Answer (score -1):

Line up $n-1$ sticks in a row, creating $n$ gaps.

If we distribute $k$ dots in these gaps, there are $\color{green}{\binom{n+k-1}{k}}$ ways to do this;

and each such distribution corresponds to a selection of $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$,

where $x_i=m$ if the $i$th dot is in gap $m$.