# Without any computations, argue that $H_k(n)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(j)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinatorial-proofs

Let $H_k(n)$ be the number of vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k$ for which each $x_i$ is a positive integer satisfying $1\leq x_i\leq n$ and $x_1\leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_k$.

Without any computations, argue that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H_1(n) & = n & \\ \\
H_k(n) & = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(j) & k>1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Let $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ be a vector such that $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1\leq x_i\leq n$.

When $k=1$, then the vector is of length 1. Since $x_1$ is an integer between (and including) 1 and $n$, there are $n$ different choices of integers. Hence $H_1(n)=n$.

When $k=2$, then the vector is of length 2. Since $x_1$ is an integer between (and including) 1 and $n$, we have $n$ options. Now for $x_2$. We know $x_1\leq x_2$. This implies whatever $x_1$ equals $x_2$ has $n-x_1+1$ options (because $x_1$ can be the same as $x_2$). Hence $H_2(n)=n(n+x_1+1)$

- Question 1: I know there is a gap in my reasoning because if you try computing $H_2(n)$ with the formulas above, you get $H_2(n)=n(n+1)/2$. Can someone enlighten me on where my thinking is wrong?
- Question 2: Am I suppose to use counting arguments for both sides of $H_2(n)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_1(j)$ to show equally?

**I am guessing yes.**

- Question 3: How am I suppose to extend this argument for the case of generic $k$?

Comment: In your reasoning for $k=2$, $H_2(n)$ should be $$\sum_{x_1 \in [n]} (n + 1 - x_1) = n(n+1)/2$$

Comment: Thus for Question 1, I think your reasoning is not wrong, at least not wrong for $k=2$

Comment: Or maybe have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904102

Comment: @VezenBU How did you get that sum equal to n(n+1)/2?

Comment: It is just $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n-1 ) + n$

Answer (score 2):

To prove the recurrence, condition on the value $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ of $x_k$.  Explicitly, if $x_k = j$, we want to count the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1 \le \dots \le x_{k-1} \le j$, which is exactly the definition of $H_{k-1}(j)$.

Comment: Hi! I don't understand how that statement shows that $H_k(n)$ is the formula above?

Comment: We have partitioned the count of $H_k(n)$ into disjoint cases based on the value of $x_k$, so adding up the counts of these cases yields the desired total.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how that argument is enough to justify the sum. Can you perhaps rephrase that?

Comment: To better understand the argument, I recommend explicitly writing out the solutions $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for $k=3$ and $n=2$ and grouping them according to the two possible values of $x_3$.  Then notice how the two groups correspond to $H_2(1)$ and $H_2(2)$.

Comment: Okie dokie. I think I got it then. I just feel funny cause it doesn't seem like a long argument to make.