# Prove via induction $H_k(n) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(j)$ where $k>1$

Tags: induction, recursion

First yes this question is related to the problem I posted before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525591/without-any-computations-argue-that-h-kn-sum-limits-j-1n-h-k-1j). But I want to try proving this via induction this time.

Let $H_k(n)$ be the number of vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k$ for which each $x_i$ is a positive integer satisfying $1\leq x_i\leq n$ and $x_1\leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_k$. Prove
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H_1(n) & = n & \\ \\
H_k(n) & = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(j) & k>1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So the proof is the same for $i=1,2$ which I will provide below. From the previous post,
Let $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ be a vector such that $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1\leq x_i\leq n$.

When $i=1$, then the vector is of length 1. Since $x_1$ is an integer between (and including) 1 and $n$, there are $n$ different choices of integers. Hence $H_1(n)=n$.

When $i=2$, then the vector is of length 2. Since $x_1$ is an integer between (and including) 1 and $n$, we have $n$ options. Now for $x_2$. We know $x_1\leq x_2$. This implies whatever $x_1$ equals $x_2$ has $n-x_1+1$ options (because $x_1$ can be the same as $x_2$). Hence
$$
H_2(n)
= \sum\limits_{x_1\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}} (n-x_1+1)
= 1+2+\dots+n
= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

Now here is the different part. Assume that the sum is true for $i=k$. i.e.
$$ H_k(n) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(j)$$
We want to show that
$$ H_{k+1}(n) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k}(j)$$
So here is what I got so far
$$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k}(j) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{\ell=1}^j H_{k-1}(\ell)$$
I know I can repeat this continuously until I get $H_1(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is some positive integer. But that doesn't get me anywhere.

I have also tried doing the following:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k}(j) & = H_k(1) + H_k(2) + H_k(3) +\dots+H_k(n) \\
& = \sum\limits_{j=1}^1 H_{k-1}(j) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 H_{k-1}(j) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^3 H_k(j) + \dots + \sum\limits_{j=1}^n H_{k-1}(n) \\
& = nH_{k-1}(1) + (n-1)H_{k-1}(2) + (n-2)H_{k-1}(3) + \dots +H_{k-1}(n)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Again I can repeat this step again with the equation for $H_{k-1}(n)$ but I feel like I am going on a never ending battle. Any suggestions.

Comment: Let $\mathcal H_n$ be the set of $n$-vectors $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ you're counting. Notice that $x_n$ can actually be any value between $1$ and $n$ and that once you fix $x_n=k$, all other $n-1$ numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ can only take the values between $1,\cdots,k$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @Alessandro ... So how would that translate to the equations? And which string of equations that I have above would you use?

Answer (score 1):

I would have done induction on $n$: First, it's easy to see that $H_k(1)=1$ for every $k$, so that $H_k(1)=\sum_{j=1}^1H_{k-1}(1)$, for $k>1$.

Let $\mathcal H_k(n)$ be the set as of tuples $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ as in the question. You want to break $\mathcal H_k(n)$ into two subsets of which you can apply induction. In this case, you break the set into $x_k<n$ and $x_k=n$, because then you can reduce $n$, because if $x_k=n$, then you're only $k-1$ variables $x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1}$, so the number of tuples $(x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1},n)$ is just $H_{k-1}(n)$. Next, if $x_k<n$, then all other variables must be $<n$ and so we're counting $H_k(n-1)$ and you can apply induction and conclude that $$H_k(n)=H_{k-1}(n)+H_k(n-1)=\sum_{j=1}^nH_{j-1}(n)$$